# Modificar una lista desde MVC Razor y enviarla al controlador

Tags: c#, mvc, net

Buen dia, tengo un objeto que le paso a una vista desde el controlador y necesito seleccionar varios campos de un array dentro del objeto que envio a la vista y volver enviar ese objeto actualizado al controlador, para su posterior proceso, estuve viendo algunos ejemplos que ofrecen en ajax y no me funcionaron y seguramente .Net tiene todo lo necesario para realizarlo pero no estoy encontrando la doc necesaria.

De esta forma en el foreach me da error en el CheckBox

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or
> single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

```
@model PaypalBackofficeZenziya.Models.LinkPagoPaypal

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit","CrearLink","Post"))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Crear Link Pago Paypal</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdLinkPago, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IdLinkPago, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disable" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdLinkPago, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="form-horizontal dl-horizontal"> 
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> Nro Cuota  </td>
            <td> - Monto Cuota </td>
            <td> - Seleccionar Cuota </td>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var cuota in Model.Cuotas)
        {
             var seleccionado = (cuota.CuotaSeleccionada)== null ? false : cuota.CuotaSeleccionada;
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center"> @Html.LabelFor(c=>  cuota.Cuota)</td>
                
                <td class="text-center"> @Html.LabelFor(c=> cuota.Cobro) </td>

                <td class="text-center"> @Html.CheckBoxFosr(c => (bool)seleccionado)</td
                
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="btn-success">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Crear Link" class="btn btn-success" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontre la solucion, al problema del error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Templates can be used only with
> field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or
> single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

se debe a que debo manejar el null que puede venir del bool desde la base de datos desde el modelo de datos y no trabajarlo desde el mismo front-end

```
    public bool CuotaSeleccionada
    {
        get => _CuotaSeleccionada;

        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                _CuotaSeleccionada = false;
            }
            else
                _CuotaSeleccionada = (bool)value;
        }
    }
```

y Finalmente en el front-end no debo hacer ningun cast

```
    @foreach (var cuota in Model.Cuotas)
    {
         var seleccionado = (cuota.CuotaSeleccionada)== null ? false : cuota.CuotaSeleccionada;
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center"> @Html.LabelFor(c=>  cuota.Cuota)</td>
            
            <td class="text-center"> @Html.LabelFor(c=> cuota.Cobro) </td>

            <td class="text-center"> @Html.CheckBoxFor(c => cuota.CuotaSeleccionada)
        </tr>
    }
```